# class 'MaddHatter\LaravelFullcalendar\ServiceProvider' not found

Tags: laravel, service, fullcalendar, provider

I am implementing maddhatter/laravel-fullcalender for Laravel. Link to FullCalendar source code is here: https://github.com/maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar/blob/master/readme.md .

I have required it in composer under the name "maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar": "~1.1" and I have added the service provider to the third party service providers section of app.php with "MaddHatter\LaravelFullcalendar\ServiceProvider::class". I have also added the alias, "'Calendar'  => MaddHatter\LaravelFullcalendar\Facades\Calendar::class" but for some reason when I pull up the website it says, "**class 'MaddHatter\LaravelFullCalendar\ServiceProvider not found**".

I am totally lost on what is going wrong. PLEASE HELP.
Thank you

Comment: After you added it to `composer.json`, did you do `composer install`?

Comment: Try command : composer update or php artisan config:publish it will copy the MaddHatter config file to your config directory

Comment: maybe `php artisan config:clear` ? A cache-related issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should install composer and run the following command
    composer require maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar
After successfully install package, open config/app.php file and add service provider and alias.
config/app.php

'providers' => [

```
....

MaddHatter\LaravelFullcalendar\ServiceProvider::class,
```

],

'aliases' => [

```
....

'Calendar' => MaddHatter\LaravelFullcalendar\Facades\Calendar::class,
```

]

Answer (score -1):

Are you run `composer install` after require it in composer.json file?